# A new user seems to have accidentally registered twice - What to do?

Tags: discussion, new-users, user-accounts, sign-up

While reviewing suggested edits, I came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2508919) were a new user proposed an change in a way that made me think that he is actually editing his own post. But the proposing user was different to the OP (quite obviously, or the change wouldn't have been in the review queue.)

From the two involved user's activity, it seems that the new user registered as [user2579825](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2579825/user2579825) three days ago, and accidentally registered again today as [user2582585](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2582585/user2582585).

What can I (or we as a community) do in such a case? I tried to make the user aware of his mistake via a comment, but I don't know if this is sufficient. Any other ideas?

Comment: Comment and point them to the help center: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: And if commenting is not enough and he is active on both accounts creating confusion, flag for moderator's attention.

Comment: Just a note for this case: these appear to be different users, the fact that they're new seems to be all that is in common.

Comment: When I asked the question, the older user had not been on the site for a period of time longer than the newer user existed. This changed in the meanwhile: They've just both been online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick [noted in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188830/a-new-user-seems-to-have-accidentally-registered-twice-what-to-do#comment582205_188830), these are in fact two different people. The only thing that they have in common is being new, and involvement in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633988/android-listview-with-custom-autosize-textview-some-items-not-showing-properly).

However, your Spidey sense is keen when it comes to spotting this, the obvious signs are pretty much what we have here:

- Both new(ish) or unregistered accounts
- *Sometimes* older accounts with a new user making edits as if it were their own contribution
- Behavior from one indicates disenfranchisement from the other account

When you see this, you can [point them here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) as [Yannis suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188830/a-new-user-seems-to-have-accidentally-registered-twice-what-to-do#comment582124_188830) or casually ping a moderator or employee [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Only employees have the ability to merge accounts, but moderators can generally get a hold of us pretty quickly if you don't see one of us in a public room. You can also flag the post as 'other' and indicate that someone probably needs a merge, the moderators will send it to us if they agree.

Not being able to control your contributions can be a very frustrating experience so we really do appreciate a heads up (in whatever way is convenient for you) when you spot this so we can have a look.